How to set up Caddy with Let's Encrypt SSL and Duck DNS to serve multiple services running as Docker containers?
I have managed to set up VaultWarden that is only accessible on a local LAN with a lets encrypt SSL certificate using Caddy. Caddy, VaultWarden and other services run as Docker containers that run on a Raspberry Pi host.
I have setup a Duck DNS domain: test111.duckdns.org that points to my Raspberry Pi private LAN IP address.
I have added a host override in my pfSense DNS resolver settings (this was a crucial step to make it work) like so:
Host: test111
Domain: duckdns.org
IP Address: <raspberry pi IP address>

My Docker compose file:
networks:
  docker-mongoose:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.16.117.0/27"

services:
  caddy:
    image: caddy:2
    networks:
      docker-mongoose:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.117.10
    container_name: caddy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 443:443/udp # Needed for HTTP/3.
    volumes:
      - ./caddy:/usr/bin/caddy  
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile:ro
      - ./caddy-config:/config
      - ./caddy-data:/data
    environment:
      DOMAIN: "test111.duckdns.org" 
      #EMAIL: ""
      DUCKDNS_TOKEN: "<duckdns token>>"
      LOG_FILE: "/data/access.logs

   unifi-network-application:
    container_name: unifi-network-application
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/unifi-network-application:latest
    networks:
      docker-mongoose:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.117.9
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1s
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
      - 3478:3478/udp
      - 10001:10001/udp
      - 8080:8080
      - 1900:1900/udp #optional
      #- 8843:8843 #optional
      #- 8880:8880 #optional
      #- 6789:6789 #optional
      #- 5514:5514/udp #optional
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - MONGO_USER=user
      - MONGO_PASS=password
      - MONGO_HOST=unifi-db
      - MONGO_PORT=27017
      - MONGO_DBNAME=unifi-db
      - MEM_LIMIT=1024 #optional
      - MEM_STARTUP=1024 #optional
      #- MONGO_TLS= #optional
      #- MONGO_AUTHSOURCE= #optional
    volumes:
      - /home/user/docker/unifi-network-application/config:/config
    restart: unless-stopped

    unifi-db:
      etc....

  vaultwarden:
    image: vaultwarden/server:latest
    networks:
      docker-mongoose:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.117.8
    container_name: vaultwarden
    restart: always
    environment:
      DOMAIN: "https://test111.duckdns.org"
      SIGNUPS_ALLOWED: "false"
      INVITATIONS_ALLOWED: "false"
      SHOW_PASSWORD_HINT: "false"
      LOG_FILE: "/data/vaultwarden.log"
      LOG_LEVEL: "warn"
    volumes:
      - ./vw-data:/data # the path before the : can be changed
    #ports:
      #- 8888:80 # you can replace the 11001 with your preferred port

My Caddyfile:
{$DOMAIN} {
    log {
        level INFO
        output file {$LOG_FILE} {
            roll_size 10MB
            roll_keep 10
        }
    }

    # Use the ACME DNS-01 challenge to get a cert for the configured domain.
    tls {
        dns duckdns {$DUCKDNS_TOKEN}
    }

    # This setting may have compatibility issues with some browsers
    # (e.g., attachment downloading on Firefox). Try disabling this
    # if you encounter issues.
    encode zstd gzip

    # Proxy everything to Rocket
    reverse_proxy vaultwarden:80
}

This setup works fine, I can access my VaultWarden over SSL by going to https://test111.duckdns.org and it uses a Let's Encrypt certificate. I used this guide to achieve this.
However I would like it so I could use Caddy for multiple docker services. For example to visit VaultWarden I could visit https://vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org or https://service.test111.duckdns.org etc.
I have tried to change this in the Caddyfile by using wildcards:
# Wildcard SSL for all subdomains under the domain defined in the {$DOMAIN} variable
*.{$DOMAIN} {
    tls {
        dns duckdns {$DUCKDNS_TOKEN}
    }

    # Logs configuration (optional, adjust as necessary)
    log {
        level INFO
        output file {$LOG_FILE} {
            roll_size 10MB
            roll_keep 10
        }
    }

    # Default reverse proxy to a generic service if no specific service matches
    reverse_proxy service_default:80
}

# Vaultwarden Service
vaultwarden.{$DOMAIN} {
    reverse_proxy vaultwarden:80
    log {
        level INFO
        output file {$LOG_FILE} {
            roll_size 10MB
            roll_keep 10
        }
    }
}


unifi.{$DOMAIN} {
    reverse_proxy unifi-network-application:8443
    log {
        level INFO
        output file {$LOG_FILE} {
            roll_size 10MB
            roll_keep 10
        }
    }
}

I have also added the host overrides in pfSense's DNS resolver settings for the different services to point to my Docker IP addresses:
Host: unifi     
Domain: test111.duckdns.org     
IP Address: 172.16.117.9

Host: vaultwarden   
Domain: test111.duckdns.org     
IP Address: 172.16.117.8

And it can find these with nslookup:
nslookup vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org
Address: 172.16.117.8

However this doesn't work I can't access my Docker services and I get the following errors in my Caddy container:
{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.407683,"msg":"using config from file","file":"/etc/caddy/Caddyfile"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4159002,"msg":"adapted config to JSON","adapter":"caddyfile"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4204524,"logger":"admin","msg":"admin endpoint started","address":"localhost:2019","enforce_origin":false,"origins":["//localhost:2019","//[::1]:2019","//127.0.0.1:2019"]}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4216182,"logger":"tls.cache.maintenance","msg":"started background certificate maintenance","cache":"0x383a900"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4221516,"logger":"http.auto_https","msg":"server is listening only on the HTTPS port but has no TLS connection policies; adding one to enable TLS","server_name":"srv0","https_port":443}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4224873,"logger":"http.auto_https","msg":"enabling automatic HTTP->HTTPS redirects","server_name":"srv0"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4248602,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling HTTP/3 listener","addr":":443"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4254677,"msg":"failed to sufficiently increase receive buffer size (was: 208 kiB, wanted: 7168 kiB, got: 416 kiB). See https://github.com/quic-go/quic-go/wiki/UDP-Buffer-Sizes for details."}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4263346,"logger":"http.log","msg":"server running","name":"srv0","protocols":["h1","h2","h3"]}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4268074,"logger":"http.log","msg":"server running","name":"remaining_auto_https_redirects","protocols":["h1","h2","h3"]}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4269671,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling automatic TLS certificate management","domains":["vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org","unifi.test111.duckdns.org","*.test111.duckdns.org"]}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4284034,"msg":"autosaved config (load with --resume flag)","file":"/config/caddy/autosave.json"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4289424,"msg":"serving initial configuration"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4288747,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"acquiring lock","identifier":"vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4296653,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"acquiring lock","identifier":"unifi.test111.duckdns.org"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.429877,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"acquiring lock","identifier":"*.test111.duckdns.org"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4420304,"logger":"tls","msg":"storage cleaning happened too recently; skipping for now","storage":"FileStorage:/data/caddy","instance":"a16163dc-5a65-4977-a1d2-99f3861efde9","try_again":1731856827.4420183,"try_again_in":86399.999995129}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4445798,"logger":"tls","msg":"finished cleaning storage units"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.44627,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"lock acquired","identifier":"*.test111.duckdns.org"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4462702,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"lock acquired","identifier":"vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.446822,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"obtaining certificate","identifier":"*.test111.duckdns.org"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4474423,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"obtaining certificate","identifier":"vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4468448,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"lock acquired","identifier":"unifi.test111.duckdns.org"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4486356,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"obtaining certificate","identifier":"unifi.test111.duckdns.org"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4698937,"logger":"tls","msg":"waiting on internal rate limiter","identifiers":["unifi.test111.duckdns.org"],"ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory","account":""}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4699652,"logger":"tls","msg":"done waiting on internal rate limiter","identifiers":["unifi.test111.duckdns.org"],"ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory","account":""}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4700146,"logger":"tls","msg":"using ACME account","account_id":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/1972895377","account_contact":[]}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4704852,"logger":"tls","msg":"waiting on internal rate limiter","identifiers":["vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org"],"ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory","account":""}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4709487,"logger":"tls","msg":"done waiting on internal rate limiter","identifiers":["vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org"],"ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory","account":""}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.472356,"logger":"tls","msg":"using ACME account","account_id":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/1972895377","account_contact":[]}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4715934,"logger":"tls.issuance.acme","msg":"waiting on internal rate limiter","identifiers":["*.test111.duckdns.org"],"ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory","account":""}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4725082,"logger":"tls.issuance.acme","msg":"done waiting on internal rate limiter","identifiers":["*.test111.duckdns.org"],"ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory","account":""}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770427.4725654,"logger":"tls.issuance.acme","msg":"using ACME account","account_id":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/1972895377","account_contact":[]}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770428.6145887,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"trying to solve challenge","identifier":"vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org","challenge_type":"tls-alpn-01","ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770428.686017,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"trying to solve challenge","identifier":"unifi.test111.duckdns.org","challenge_type":"tls-alpn-01","ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770428.8439467,"logger":"tls.issuance.acme.acme_client","msg":"trying to solve challenge","identifier":"*.test111.duckdns.org","challenge_type":"dns-01","ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770429.2492373,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"challenge failed","identifier":"unifi.test111.duckdns.org","challenge_type":"tls-alpn-01","problem":{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns","title":"","detail":"no valid A records found for unifi.test111.duckdns.org; DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up AAAA for unifi.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning","instance":"","subproblems":[]}}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770429.2495832,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"validating authorization","identifier":"unifi.test111.duckdns.org","problem":{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns","title":"","detail":"no valid A records found for unifi.test111.duckdns.org; DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up AAAA for unifi.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning","instance":"","subproblems":[]},"order":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/1972895377/323713330197","attempt":1,"max_attempts":3}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770430.672126,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"trying to solve challenge","identifier":"unifi.test111.duckdns.org","challenge_type":"http-01","ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770431.3256845,"logger":"tls.issuance.acme.acme_client","msg":"cleaning up solver","identifier":"*.test111.duckdns.org","challenge_type":"dns-01","error":"no memory of presenting a DNS record for \"_acme-challenge.test111.duckdns.org\" (usually OK if presenting also failed)"}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770431.5020833,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"could not get certificate from issuer","identifier":"*.test111.duckdns.org","issuer":"acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org-directory","error":"[*.test111.duckdns.org] solving challenges: presenting for challenge: could not determine zone for domain \"_acme-challenge.test111.duckdns.org\": unexpected response code 'SERVFAIL' for _acme-challenge.test111.duckdns.org. (order=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/1972895377/323713330907) (ca=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory)"}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770431.5025475,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"will retry","error":"[*.test111.duckdns.org] Obtain: [*.test111.duckdns.org] solving challenges: presenting for challenge: could not determine zone for domain \"_acme-challenge.test111.duckdns.org\": unexpected response code 'SERVFAIL' for _acme-challenge.test111.duckdns.org. (order=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/1972895377/323713330907) (ca=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory)","attempt":1,"retrying_in":60,"elapsed":4.05621756,"max_duration":2592000}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770438.8788044,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"challenge failed","identifier":"vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org","challenge_type":"tls-alpn-01","problem":{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns","title":"","detail":"DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up A for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning; no valid AAAA records found for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org","instance":"","subproblems":[]}}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770438.8789387,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"validating authorization","identifier":"vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org","problem":{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns","title":"","detail":"DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up A for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning; no valid AAAA records found for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org","instance":"","subproblems":[]},"order":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/1972895377/323713330097","attempt":1,"max_attempts":3}

{"level":"info","ts":1731770440.2944498,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"trying to solve challenge","identifier":"vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org","challenge_type":"http-01","ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770450.1866465,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"challenge failed","identifier":"unifi.test111.duckdns.org","challenge_type":"http-01","problem":{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns","title":"","detail":"no valid A records found for unifi.test111.duckdns.org; no valid AAAA records found for unifi.test111.duckdns.org","instance":"","subproblems":[]}}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770450.1867352,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"validating authorization","identifier":"unifi.test111.duckdns.org","problem":{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns","title":"","detail":"no valid A records found for unifi.test111.duckdns.org; no valid AAAA records found for unifi.test111.duckdns.org","instance":"","subproblems":[]},"order":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/1972895377/323713337107","attempt":2,"max_attempts":3}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770450.1868649,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"could not get certificate from issuer","identifier":"unifi.test111.duckdns.org","issuer":"acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org-directory","error":"HTTP 400 urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns - no valid A records found for unifi.test111.duckdns.org; no valid AAAA records found for unifi.test111.duckdns.org"}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770450.1870203,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"will retry","error":"[unifi.test111.duckdns.org] Obtain: [unifi.test111.duckdns.org] solving challenge: unifi.test111.duckdns.org: [unifi.test111.duckdns.org] authorization failed: HTTP 400 urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns - no valid A records found for unifi.test111.duckdns.org; no valid AAAA records found for unifi.test111.duckdns.org (ca=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory)","attempt":1,"retrying_in":60,"elapsed":22.738644345,"max_duration":2592000}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770460.5871239,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"challenge failed","identifier":"vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org","challenge_type":"http-01","problem":{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns","title":"","detail":"DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up A for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning; DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up AAAA for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning","instance":"","subproblems":[]}}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770460.5872557,"logger":"tls.acme_client","msg":"validating authorization","identifier":"vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org","problem":{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns","title":"","detail":"DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up A for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning; DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up AAAA for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning","instance":"","subproblems":[]},"order":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/1972895377/323713378127","attempt":2,"max_attempts":3}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770460.5873518,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"could not get certificate from issuer","identifier":"vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org","issuer":"acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org-directory","error":"HTTP 400 urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns - DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up A for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning; DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up AAAA for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning"}

{"level":"error","ts":1731770460.5875442,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"will retry","error":"[vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org] Obtain: [vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org] solving challenge: vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org: [vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org] authorization failed: HTTP 400 urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns - DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up A for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning; DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up AAAA for vaultwarden.test111.duckdns.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning (ca=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory)","attempt":1,"retrying_in":60,"elapsed":33.140588664,"max_duration":2592000}

I'm essentially trying to achieve this, but with Caddy and duck dns. But I'm not sure if this is possible or if I'm configuring Caddy  incorrectly.

I managed to figure it out. It turns out I needed to change each host override
in PfSense to the local IP of the raspberry pi that hosts each service instead of the docker address that is assigned to each service container. My DuckDNS domain seems to work fine after this change.
